# VersionOne SDK: How to Associate Defect with Epic?

Tags: c#, sdk, versionone

I’ve written some C# code to create a VersionOne defect.  That code works correctly.  I now have to associate the newly created defect with an Epic (Portfolio item).  For a test, I manually associated a defect with an Epic through the V1 GUI.  When I use the rest API to display the defect, I see:

```
<Relation name="Super">
<Asset href="/VersionOne/rest-1.v1/Data/Epic/493072" idref="Epic:493072"/>
</Relation>
```

I assumed that making the relationship with other defects to other Epics was a matter of setting the “Super” attribute with the appropriate Epic value.  So, in my code I tried:

```
IAttributeDefinition superAttribute = storyType.GetAttributeDefinition("Super");
newDefect.SetAttributeValue(superAttribute, "Epic:493074");
```

Unfortunately, this throws the following exception when I run the code:

> ERROR: Connection exception!
>
> *** VersionOne.SDK.APIClient
>
> *** Error writing to output stream VersionOne.SDK.APIClient.APIException: Violation'Invalid'Defect.Super

Does anyone know how to associate a newly created defect with an Epic?

Comment: did you ever get this working?

Comment: Yes.  Thanks for reminding me.  I need to add my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did eventually resolve this.  I first had to understand that V1 no longer uses Epics.  It now calls them [Portfolio Items](https://community.versionone.com/VersionOne-Lifecycle/The_Agile_Process/Portfolio_Planning/Feature_Breakdown/00_Portfolio_Item_Overview).  I then went through the process of manually associating a defect to a Portfolio Item to determine what fields within the GUI are used.  Then, I spoke with my admin and learned that I was trying to access a part of the Portfolio Tree I was not authorized to.  Once he granted me access, the above code in my post worked.